# Printing SAP Crystal Reports using Java

Tags: java, printing, crystal-reports

I am trying to print reports using the Crystal Report API based on this [example](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+Java++SDK+Samples#CrystalReportsJavaSDKSamples-Exporting/Printing).

```
reportClientDoc.open(reportpath+reportName, 0);
//Create and set print options.
PrintReportOptions printOptions = new PrintReportOptions();
printOptions.setPrinterName(printerName); //Note: Printer 'printername' must already be configured at Operating system level.
printOptions.setJobTitle(reportName); // job title by the report file name
printOptions.setPrinterDuplex(PrinterDuplex.simplex);
printOptions.setPaperSource(PaperSource.auto);
printOptions.setPaperSize(PaperSize.paperA4);
printOptions.setNumberOfCopies(1);
printOptions.setCollated(false);
reportClientDoc.getPrintOutputController().printReport(printOptions);
```

But I can't get it working, I receive a `java.util.concurrent.CancellationException`:

```
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
    at com.businessobjects.crystalreports.printer.bean.Printer.X(Unknown Source)
    at com.businessobjects.crystalreports.printer.bean.ReportPrinter.print(Unknown Source)
    at com.businessobjects.crystalreports.printer.bean.ReportPrinter.print(Unknown Source)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.printReport(SourceFile:742)
    at my.test.crystal.GenerateReport.doGet(GenerateReport.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.awt.print.PrinterAbortException
    at com.businessobjects.crystalreports.viewer.core.ReportPagePrinter.print(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.printPage(RasterPrinterJob.java:1936)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1431)
    at com.businessobjects.crystalreports.viewer.core.ReportPagePrinter.print(Unknown Source)
```

The very strange thing is that the example worked previously in another project, but no longer on my local environment! I probably changed something but I can't figure out what :(

I tried with several printers (local and network) but the scenario is always the same: I can see the job during a very short time in printer job list but after less than 1 second, it vanishes and I receive the exception.

I am using Tomcat 7 and I tried with JDK1.6 and 1.7 (thinking about a JDK issue?) but there's no change.

If someone can give me some leads because currently, I am totally stuck.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add ReportViewer.jar to your libraries.
For code completion, this doesn't seem necessary, but it is for printing.

Comment: Thank you for your input but I don't know where I can find this jar (google did not help). Anyway, I am not working anymore on this project, and without answer to this issue, I finally had to manage the printing by using the Unix command 'lp' :-/